# Using domxpath to parse a some complex nested html

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I'm having issues figuring out how to get certain elements of text out of a rather more complex html page than any I can find examples of online.

The site I'm trying to parse is a property website and in the html they have things like the price and the status of the property. If we take the status of the property as an example I'm trying to get 'For Sale' out of the following snippet of html:

```
<div class="repeating container of property details">
<div class="firstlevel other class too">
    <div class="secondlevel other class too">
        <div class="thirdlevel">
            <div class="fourthlevel">
                <span class="thisspan">For Sale</span>
                <span class="someotherspan">Something else</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then with the following php I try to extract what I need.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$properties = $xpath->query('//div[@class="repeating container of property details"]');

foreach($properties as $container) {

    $node = $xpath->query('div[@class="firstlevel other class too"]'
        . '/div[@class="secondlevel other class too"]'
        . '/div[@class="thirdlevel"]'
        . '/div[@class="fourthlevel"]'
        . '/span[@class="thisspan"]', $container); // returns a DOMNodeList  
    $result = $node->item(0)->value; // get the first node in the list which is a DOMAttr
    echo 'value: '.$result.'<br/>';
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
Undefined property: DOMElement::$value
```

It's clearly not selecting what I'm trying to get hold of and nothing else I've tried so far seems to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try querying starting at $properties `$node = $properties->query('div[@class="firstlevel other class too"]'` or add double slash to the xpath `$node = $xpath->query('//div[@class="firstlevel other class too"]'`. Do that out of the loop since you are passing the full xpath to the element, no need to iterate elements in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You're fetching an element node (the `span`), not an attribute node. Element nodes do not have a `$value` property. Use the `$textContent` property:

```
$result = $node->item(0)->textContent;
```

Or you cast the node list to a string in the Xpath expression:

```
$result = $xpath->evaluate('string(div[@class="firstlevel other class too"]'
    . '/div[@class="secondlevel other class too"]'
    . '/div[@class="thirdlevel"]'
    . '/div[@class="fourthlevel"]'
    . '/span[@class="thisspan"])', $container); // returns a DOMNodeList  
echo 'value: '.$result.'<br/>';
```

This will only work with `DOMXpath::evaluate()`, `DOMXpath::query()` does only support expressions that return node lists.